# How to get the date of every last Monday from a giving date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to capture the Monday" date from a giving date.
so today is 4/10/2014 I need to return 4/07/2014 since Monday was 4/07/2014

and if I do 02/07/2014 it should return 02/03/2014 since it was the last Monday.

How can I do that using MySQL?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`WEEKDAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

```
SELECT '2014-04-10' - INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2014-04-10') DAY;
```

(zero is for monday). Substutute your date instead of `2014-04-10` (but it must be valid date). So: you'll subtract number of days past since last monday.

If given date string isn't in standard MySQL date format, use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert it